# Remove glassy effect from rows in WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to style a ListView in my WPF based application. What I'm trying to do, is to create a gradient effect on the mouseover on rows. But what I don't want is the standard glassy effect that is added to the rows. Even with my own styling (below), the glassy effect is still there.

XAML Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#39B4E7" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#4297BB" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

ListView

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentProject}" Margin="3" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShortName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Owner" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User.Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Versions" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Versions.Count}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

New XAML Style

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#39B4E7" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#4297BB" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Each `ListViewItem` resides within a contianer, and that container is what gets the background on selection/hover. So you have to set a value for the the `ItemContainerStyle` attribute on the `ListView`.

example...

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}" />
```

the style..

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00000000" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

**Edit:**
So for your case, you can keep everything, just stick that style in your `ResourceDictionary` and add the `ItemContainerStyle` attribute on the `ListView`. Hope this helps, let me know if you get stuck.

This is what I used to do before, but it eventually got tedious so I extended the `ListView` control to handle this automatically and added an attribute for the Hover/Selection color.

**Updated Code:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentProject}" Margin="3" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ShortName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Owner" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User.Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Versions" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Versions.Count}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

** The resource file**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="#39B4E7" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#4297BB" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00000000" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I have added the new XAML from my project to the question!

Comment: Okay, give me a second to try it out your new xaml.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed what you did. You should have kept your old style the same, with the IsMouseOver and IsSelectedTriggers and just copy/pasted the style I gave you exactly as it is, because the highlight/selection colors the `ListView` uses are SystemColors, so you need to override them, like I did above. So just copy/paste it exactly like I've got it and handle your triggers in your own style.

Comment: There, I updated the code to what you should have in my post.

Comment: Copied your updated code into my XAML and now the ListView isn't styled at all!